# How can i call an already deployed contract with struct as parameters from a new contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, struct

I want to call some function in a contract B from a contract A. In my contract B I have some function who's signature is  `function execute(ExecutionInfo[] calldata executionInfos)` where `ExecutionInfo` is the following defined struct in the contract B

```
struct ExecutionInfo {
        address module;
        bytes data;
        uint256 value;
    }
```

My question is how can I call that function if I do not have access to the contract B struct in my contract A ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call access data from `contract B` if it has a view function that returns `ExecutionInfo` which will most probable be stored in mapping.

In that case you'll have to create an interface of `contract B` inside the code of `contract A` than you can access the data from `contract B`

Ideally in working condition **Contract B** should look like this

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract ContractB {

    struct ExecutionInfo {
        address module;
        bytes data;
        uint256 value;
    }

    mapping (address => ExecutionInfo) public ExecutionInfos;

    function AddExecutionInfo(bytes memory _data, uint256 _value) public {
        ExecutionInfos[msg.sender].module = msg.sender;
        ExecutionInfos[msg.sender].data = _data;
        ExecutionInfos[msg.sender].value = _value;
    }

    function GetExecutionInfo() public view returns (address, bytes memory, uint256){
        return(ExecutionInfos[msg.sender].module, ExecutionInfos[msg.sender].data, ExecutionInfos[msg.sender].value);
    }

}
```

and **Contract A** should look like this to access data from `contract B`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

interface IContractB {
    function GetExecutionInfo(address _address) external view returns (address, bytes memory, uint256);
}

contract ContractA {

    IContractB contractB;

    constructor (address _contractAddress) {
        contractB = IContractB(_contractAddress);
    }


    function getInformationFromContractB (address _address) public view returns (address, bytes memory, uint256){
        return (contractB.GetExecutionInfo(_address));
    }
}
```

If you have any further issue lemme know

Comment: what if the contract has no getter ? Is it still possible to call that function ?

Comment: No i don't think so

Comment: What if I import the struct in my original contract and pass it as an argument ?

Comment: Like something like this  ReservoirV6_0_0.ExecutionInfo myStruct;